# How to send flash messages along with response object/s for REST call in Grails

Tags: flash, rest, grails

In Grails 2.3.* REST Controller, I am using respond to render instance of an object in response to a REST call.
I wonder if it possible to send multiple objects [instance + flash.message ] using Grails respond method.

Are there any conventions to send  flash messages along with expected result for REST API call.

```
    request.withFormat {
        form {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: "${resourceName}.label".toString(), default: resourceClassName), instance.id])
            redirect instance
        }
        '*' { respond instance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
```

Comment: My app is a Single-Page Application (SPA) which is not using any views generated by Grails. The front-end is static html pages with JavaScript (AngularJS, Backbone...) which calls RESTful API hosted on Grails backend.  Backend is designed complete stateless REST services.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation about flash and it's scope (http://grails.org/doc/1.3.9/ref/Controllers/flash.html), I understand that the data you put in it is managed by the session for you, which should mean you can return a result and grails should manage the flash content for you.

Simply try adding a flash."paramName" before your response and you should hopefully find it available in your headers client side.